# SSRS 2016 Data source won't display Oracle connection type

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, oracle11g, ssrs-2016

I have a couple of new SSRS 2016 installations. Both of them fail to show the Oracle connection type. They will show Oracle Essbase, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

The full Oracle client is installed in both cases and I can successfully make a connection using the OLEDB connection type and invoking the Oracle OLEDB driver. Unfortunately, I have hundreds of reports that I'm moving to these new instances and the OLEDB client behaves slightly differently than the .Net client and causes errors, specifically on Oracle parameters.

I have looked through all the Microsoft documentation and I don't see why it won't give me the Oracle connection type. I have never had this problem on SSRS 2008R2 or 2012 installations.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I did the following

I downloaded the 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x64

From here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

I made sure the environment variables for ORACLE_HOME, PATH and TNS_ADMIN were configured correctly.

I restarted the SQL SERVER Reporting Services Service, I then went into the report server host machine and installed SSRS 2016 Report Builder.  From there I tested the Oracle Database connection using inline SQL.

Hope this helps!!